# Compute $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos{x}-1}{\ln{(1+\sin^2{x})}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The limit is $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos{x}-1}{\ln{(1+\sin^2{x})}},$$

I'm trying to rewrite the function as $$\frac{\cos^2{x}}{\ln{(1+\sin^2{x})}}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos{x}}-\frac{1}{\ln{(1+\sin^2{x})}}$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

**Note:** that L'Hopital's rule is not allowed and I should only be able using sin, cos (no sec and csc).

### EDIT:

I forgott to square the $\sin^2(x)$. Sorry about that :/

Comment: Rewrite it as$$\begin{align}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{\ln(1+\sin(x))}&=\frac u{\ln(1+u)}\frac x{\sin(x)}\frac{\cos(x)-1}x\\&=\frac1{(\ln(1+u))'}\frac1{(\sin(x))'}(\cos(x))'\bigg|_{u=0,~x=0}\end{align}$$where $u=\sin(x)$. All three of these limits should be fundamental...

Comment: Can you elaborate on the details? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Can you see the equality on the first line?

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. Forgot something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475238/compute-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-0-frac-cosx-1-ln1-sinx#comment5114069_2475238):

Notice that

$$\frac{\cos(x)-1}{\ln(1+\sin^2(x))}=\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x^2}\left(\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\frac{\ln(1+u)}u\right)^{-1}$$

where $u=\sin^2(x)$. As $x\to0$, $u\to0$, and since we have, by definition of the derivative:

$$\frac d{dx}\sin(x)\bigg|_{x=0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$$

$$\frac d{du}\ln(1+u)\bigg|_{u=0}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}u=1$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x^2}=-\frac12$$

(which are all fundamental and well-known limits, the last may be derived via series or integral forms)

Thus,

> $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{\ln(1+\sin^2(x))}=-\frac12\cdot(1^2\cdot1)^{-1}=-\frac12$$

Comment: Check my edit please. Does it change your method?

Comment: If you want to know how to evaluate the cosine limit via integrals, we have$$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\int_0^1\int_0^t\cos(xu)~{\rm d}u~{\rm d}t\to\int_0^1\int_0^t1~{\rm d}u~{\rm d}t=\frac12$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\cos x-1}{\log(1+\sin^2 x)} = \underbrace{\frac{-2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\sin^2 x}}_{\to -1/2}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\sin^2 x}{\log(1+\sin^2 x)}}_{\to 1}.$$

Comment: How do you motivate the limits of the RHS? I don't think they are so obvious.

Comment: @Parseval: through the change of variable $\sin(x)=z$, the whole problem boils down to the elementary limits $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}{z}=1$ and $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\log(1+z)}{z}=1$.

Comment: Se my edit, sorry :/

Comment: @Parseval: answer updated accordingly. For the future, please avoid *chamaleon questions*.

Comment: Thanks, but what are chamaleon questions?

Comment: @Parseval: questions asking for something particular, then suddenly changing. They tend to waste valuable efforts, so, when realizing a crucial   typo occurred in a question, it is best to ask a new question rather than changing the previous topic and make people disgruntled.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought maybe it was unnecessary to ask an almost identical question. Will think about this in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Using the series forms:
$$\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \dotsb,
\;\forall x$$
and
$$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3} -  \dotsb,\;x\in(-1,1] $$
then
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(x)-1}{\ln(1+\sin^2(x))}
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\left[1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \dotsb\right] - 1}{\sin^2(x) - \frac{[\sin^2(x)]^2}{2}+\frac{[\sin^2(x)]^3}{3} -  \dotsb}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \dotsb}{\sin^2(x)\left[1- \frac{\sin^2(x)}{2} + \frac{\sin^4(x)}{3} - \dotsb\right]} \cdot \frac{\tfrac{1}{x^2}}{\tfrac{1}{x^2}}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\frac12 +\frac{x^2}{4}-\dotsb}{\underbrace{\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^2}_{\to 1} \left[1- \underbrace{\frac{\sin^2(x)}{2} + \frac{\sin^4(x)}{3} - \dotsb}_{\to 0}\right] }
= \frac{-\tfrac{1}{2} + 0}{1\cdot 1} = -\frac12
\end{align}